# Repeated values in group_concat

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php, group-by

I have two tables, first the table food and Second is Activity:

```
INSERT INTO food
    (`id`, `foodName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'food1'),
    (2, 'food2'),
    (3, 'food3'),
    (4, 'food4'),
    (5, 'food5'),
    (6, 'food6'),
;
CREATE TABLE Activity
    (`id` int,`place` varchar(14),`food_id` int,`timing` TIME,`date_and_time` DATETIME)
;
INSERT INTO Activity
    (`id`,`place`, `food_id`,`timing`,`date_and_time`)
VALUES
    (1, 'place1', 1, '10:30am','2013-05-01'),
    (2, 'place1', 1, '12:30pm','2013-05-01'),
    (3, 'place1', 1, '04:30pm','2013-05-01'),
    (4, 'place2', 2, '10:30am','2013-05-02'),
    (5, 'place2', 2, '12:30pm','2013-05-02'),
    (6, 'place2', 2, '4:30pm','2013-05-02'),
    (7, 'place1', 2, '10:30am','2013-05-02'),
    (8, 'place1', 2, '12:30pm','2013-05-02'),
    (9, 'place1', 2, '4:30pm','2013-05-02'),
    (10, 'place2', 3, '10:30am','2013-05-03'),
    (11, 'place2', 3, '12:30pm','2013-05-03'),
    (12, 'place2', 3, '4:30pm','2013-05-03')
;
```

For now I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.activity_type AS Activity, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS Products,
    CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(p.category_id SEPARATOR ',  ') USING utf8) 
      AS Categories
FROM 
    food AS p
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT activity_type
           , prod_id
      FROM activity 
      WHERE activity_type <> '' 
      GROUP BY activity_type
             , prod_id
    ) AS a
    ON p.id = a.prod_id
GROUP BY 
    activity_type
ORDER BY 
    Products DESC ;
```

Could you please help me, I need output in the below format:

```
place | food_id | Timings             |                              |
      |         |---------------------|Date                          |
      |         |Time1 |Time2 | Time3 |                              |
---------------+----------+------------------------------------------|
place1 | 1      | 10:30am| 12:30pm| 4:30pm |2013-05-01(MAX timestamp)|          
place2 | 1      | 10:30am| 12:30am| 4:30am |2013-05-01(MAX timestamp)|
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct query?  You have columns being like `activity_type`, `prod_id` and `category_id` but those are not in your tables that you provided.

Comment: I'm sorry to mention this, for some reasons i changed the columns name.

Answer (score 1):

If your `date_and_time` values are always the same, use this query:

```
select place, food_id, '10:30am' as Time1, '12:30pm' as Time2, '4:30pm' as Time3, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date_and_time), '%Y-%m-%d') as Date from Activity group by food_id, place;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, it's better to use PIVOT. the below link shows how it works : 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: MySQL has no `PIVOT` clause. Your link is for SQL-Server.